# How do I change the text on a button in AS3 (dynamically)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, dynamic

I have created my own button class called custom_btn.  I created it on the timeline and have exported it for use in ActionScript.  I can make an instance of my button, and add it to the screen fine.

The button has a dynamic text field that I would like to change the text in. I have tried to give the text field a name on the time line and the access it when I make the button, but I get an error (I think this is because the name isn't being saved to the class).  How do I change the text?

I want to do something like this:

```
var myButton:custom_btn = new custom_btn();
myButton.caption = "foo";
```

Comment: If caption is the name of the TextField, try myButton.caption.text = "foo";

Comment: I am creating the button with action script code.  If I give it a name on the timeline it doesn't get saved.  If there is a way to save the textfield name I would like to know.  I try: put a textfield over my button, then convert to symbol.  If I pick the newly created button from the library the textfield doesn't have a name.

Comment: myButtonInstanceName.myLabelId.text

Comment: @The_asMan : please read my comment directly above your response.

Comment: When I try to access the textField I get: TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.

Comment: then post the code for custom_btn

Comment: This question has already been answered.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584787/how-to-access-a-movie-clip-object-inside-a-button-object-in-as3-flash-cs4

Comment: @crooksy88 No, it isn't the same question.  I don't need to access the text inside of the frame of the button.

Comment: @The_asMan  As I stated in the question, I created the button on the timeline.  My code is as follows: var myButton:custom_btn = new custom_btn();

Comment: Boundless if you do not post the custom_btn code we can not help you.

Comment: @The_asMan How do I post the code, when I make the button on the timeline?  I click "export for actionScript" after making the button.  If I try to click the green check mark next to class that says "validate class definition" I get a popup that reads "A definition for this class could not be found in the classpath, so wone will be automatically generated in the SWF file upon export".  I must be missing something if there is a way to get to the auto generated button code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that I needed to make the button a MovieClip.  Making the button a MovieClip allowed me to give the text field a name.  I called the MovieClip "testBtn_mc", and the dynamic textfield inside it is called button_txt.  The code then looks like:

```
var button:MovieClip;
button = new testBtn_mc();
button.button_txt.text = "New Text";
button.buttonMode = true;
button.mouseChlidren=false;
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some confusion here.

If you have created your own class called custom_btn (which ideally should lead with an uppercase letter) then try this...

Ensure you have a symbol in your library with the name Custom_btn.

Double click on the symbol to open in on the stage and add a dynamic text field. Embed the font glyphs if necessary and give it an instance name of txt.

Back in the library, ensure that symbol has Export for ActionScript and Export in frame 1 ticked in the symbol properties.

Ensure the Class: path points to the Custom_btn.as file. e.g. com.Custom_btn if the Custom_btn.as file sits within a folder named com.

```
package com {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class Custom_btn extends MovieClip {

        public function Custom_btn() {
            // constructor code
        }
    }

}
```

Then within your document class:

```
var myButton:Custom_btn = new Custom_btn();

addChild(myButton);

myButton.txt.text = "foo";
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things you can try:

1) Try not converting the text field to its own symbol. I rarely find this necessary. Instead, put the field on the stage and name it. If you name it 'caption' the code you want to set the text is:

```
myButton.caption.text = "foo";
```

2) Declare a public variable in your class named the same as your text field.

```
public var caption:TextField;
```

3) Use a system font - at least for now. This will make sure that something shows up, and it's not a font issue. Make sure to embed the font of your choosing properly if you decide to switch to non-system font.

I hope This helps you out.